# Counting database items with join

Tags: sql, ormlite

Using ORMLite, I want to count the number of database items that fit certain criteria.  A simplified version of my database is as follows:

```
Employee Table:
 employeeId
 departmentId

Department Table:
 departmentId

Salary Table:
 employeeId
 payGrade
```

Suppose I want to count the number of employees from a subset of departments that are at certain pay grade.  When I try something like the following, I get an exception reporting that only one select column is allowed.

```
salaryQB.selectColumns(salaryQB.EMPLOYEE_ID);
salaryQB.where().eq(salaryQB.PAY_GRADE, 12);
employeeQB.where.in(Employee.DEPARTMENT_ID, departmentList)
      .and().in(employeeQB.EMPLOYEE_ID, salaryQB);

employeeQB.setCountOf(true);
count = dao.countOf(employeeQB.prepare());
```

But code like this returns the following error:

> RuntimeException (java.sql.SQLException: Inner query must have only 1
>   select column specified instead of 2)

Is there any way to do this short of writing a raw SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrm.  I can't see any problems with your code @Jeff.  I've improved the exception message in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) to show the actual field names for the future but that won't help you right now:

> Inner query must have only 1 select column specified instead of 2: [id, foreign]

The message is [obviously] trying to tell you that you have specified more than one `selectColumns(...)` in the `salaryQB` inner `QueryBuilder`.  But you seem to be only selecting one column here:

```
salaryQB.selectColumns(salaryQB.EMPLOYEE_ID);
```

I don't see where the `salaryQB` is defined but maybe there is some more code somewhere else that also is using `selectColumns`?  I've tried to reproduce the error in the `testInnerCountOf()` method towards the bottom of the [`QueryBuilderTest` unit test](http://goo.gl/rUHSO) but it seems to work fine.

If you can reproduce this in a unit test or if you can see how my unit test differs from your config then let me know.

**Edit:**

As of version 4.22 (from 9/2012), [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) now supports simple JOIN statements.  So your query can be simplified to:

```
salaryQB.where().eq(salaryQB.PAY_GRADE, 12);
employeeQB.join(salaryQB);
employeeQB.where().in(Employee.DEPARTMENT_ID, departmentList);
employeeQB.setCountOf(true);
count = dao.countOf(employeeQB.prepare());
```

Comment: Sorry to waste your time Gray, I was about to delete the question.  The `in` statement was a red herring; the real problem was that I accidentally called `salaryQB.selectColumns(salaryQB.EMPLOYEE_ID);` twice; once from a helper method.

Comment: Np Jeff.  The query was interesting enough that I'm happy to add it to my unit test collection.  Improving the exception message would have helped you as well so that's a good addition.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer @JeffAxelrod to use the new JOIN functionality added in 4.22.

Comment: @Gray: Hey, I just wanna add, that if you do not specifically select any column (which means you wanna select all), it tells you `Inner query must have only 1 select column specified instead of 0: []` which is a bit confusing (that it says 0).

Comment: YOu did a `select *`?   Yeah it might not handle that @Jaa-c.

Comment: @Gray: Yes. It's no a big problem, but it confused me for a while :)

Comment: I've submitted a bug request and will improve the error message in a future release @Jaa-c.  Thanks for the feedback.